# py is version 3.11 and python is 3.8

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I am using Windows 11 and have both Python versions 3.11 and 3.8 installed. When I execute the command `py --version`, it displays `Python 3.11.4`. Similarly, `python --version` shows `Python 3.8.0`.

Here is a screenshot of my PATH environment variable configuration:

[image]

I want to set the default Python version to 3.8 when using the py command. How can I achieve this? I've tried modifying the PATH variable, but it seems to default to Python 3.11. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I try to get help from chatgpt.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the top PATH entry that ends in Python38 it should ignore Python3.8 and use Python3.11 instead.

If you want to switch between Python versions easier in the future you can use a Python version manager https://pyenv-win.github.io/pyenv-win/

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the default interpreter version that `py.exe` will run for you by setting up a `py.ini` file in either `%LOCALAPPDATA%` (usually `\Users\your_username\AppData\Local`) or in the same folder that `py.exe` is in.

You probably want your `py.ini` to contain something like:

```
[defaults]
python=3.11
```

Though, it may be that you already have a `py.ini` file specifying 3.8 as the default, and just removing that should get it to pick the highest version installed, if you don't specify anything more specific. If you run `py -0`, it should show you all the versions it's aware of, with a `*` next to the current default.